# How does RAND() in SQL query actually work

Tags: mysql, sql

How does the following query actually work?

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Does it sort **all** records in the source database first and just truncate it to get 1 row then?

Answer (score 2):

This question has more to do with `LIMIT` query optimization than how does `RAND()` work.

From [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html) (**bold emphasis mine**):

> If you combine **LIMIT** row_count **with ORDER BY**, MySQL **ends** the sorting **as soon as it has found the first row_count** rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result.
>
> If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast. **If a filesort** must be done, **all rows** that match the query without the LIMIT clause **are selected**, and most or all of them are sorted, **before the first row_count are found**. After the initial rows have been found, MySQL does not sort any remainder of the result set.

Comment: What does it mean by "filesort"?

Comment: Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. Check the EXPLAIN plan and see if _Using filesort_ appears there.

Comment: So it will perform filesort for query that uses `RAND()` (because it doesn't related to the index) and sort "most or all of rows"?

Comment: I do not play with MySQL that much, but my guess is your EXPLAIN plan will show you that it is using both _temporary_ and _filesort_, so answer to your question according to docs is: __yes__.

Comment: Here's the `EXPLAIN` result -- http://i.imgur.com/t81yWm8.png. Does it mean that it sorted all rows (in my case 50) via filesort first and then just truncate it to 1 row? It doesn't clear for me unfortunately

Comment: It says so in docs so I'd assume: __YES__. I'm not deep or at any level inside MySQL code to see what's going on internally, but there are docs for users like us :)

Comment: Why do you think so? I just re-read the quoted manual. Look at this statement -- "most or all of them are sorted, **before the first row_count are found**". Well, doesn't it mean that it stops sorting after selecting limited number of rows?

Comment: It obviously does. If a row_count condition is satisfied why would it still be sorting? Makes no sense, I'm sorry for the confusion. I've added bolding on the phrase in my answer.

Comment: But why did you say that it sorts all rows and the truncates the resulting set to 1 row then?

Comment: I meant that it sorts the rows and tries to satisfy the condition at the same time. It's more of a _top-N heapsort_ for me. Don't think of me as a book, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Order by operation is performed before limiting the result.

To get a random record in good performance, you must use another approach.

A solution is :
If you have an id that is sequential you can create a random number and fetch that record only by where clause:

```
Select * from t 
where id>(select * from 
  (select rand()*10000)t1
 ) limit 1;
```

Where 10000 is the biggest id in your table.

To making the query more dynamic we can use:

```
SET @m:=rand()*(select max(id) from t); 
SELECT * FROM t WHERE id > @m LIMIT 1;
```

And also this works:

```
Select * from t 
where 
  id>(select * from(select rand()*max(id) from t) t1)
limit 1;
```

But following query is incorrect and shows only approximately  0.5 percent of records in the beginning. And I don't know why:

```
Select * from t 
where 
  id>rand()*(select max(id) from t) 
limit 1;
```

Comment: Ok, so it can take a lot of time sorting a lot of elements that I don't really want

Comment: @FrozenHeart yes it takes a lot of time.

Comment: on mysql everything takes a lot of time

Comment: @dllhell I change the answer to show that mysql can be fast.

Comment: This way you'll get ids with gap before more often.

Comment: @vp_arth yes you are right. If gaps happen less, the solution is more precise.

Comment: I test this today on 10M rows(without gaps) and on 1000 runs it never returns id > 10k... So strange math..

Comment: @vp_arth you must use second query or `id>rand()*10000000`

Comment: But why `max(id)` is not work? `10000000` const cause same results, all are less than 10k.

Comment: @vp_arth what happens when you use it? (I did not test it)

Comment: @vp_arth I don't know why this happens. I will test it and respond. Thank you.

Comment: `SET @m:=rand()*(select max(id) from t); SELECT * FROM t WHERE id > @m LIMIT 1;` works correct.

Comment: @vp_arth I don't know why but by putting it in sub-query problem solved. I will change my answer.